# Load navigation properties from a junction table with same types

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactProfile> ContactProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("Persons")]
public class Person : Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Organization Employer { get; set; }
}

[Table("Organizations")]
public class Organization : Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContactProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Profile { get; set; }
}
```

with following fluent API mapping:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Profiles)
                .WithRequired(c => c.Contact)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasMany(c => c.ContactProfiles)
                .WithRequired(c => c.Profile)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

My BreezeApi method:

```
public IQueryable<Contact> Contacts()
{
    var contacts = _contextProvider.Context.Contacts
        .Include("Profiles")
        //.Include("Profiles.Contact") // Object expected on client side
        .Include("Addresses")

    return contacts;
}
```

When i want to retrieve the data with the breeze query:

```
var query = entityQuery.from("Contacts");
```

a object expected exception will be raised from BreezeJS:

```
TypeError: Object expected
   at Anonymous function (../breeze.debug.js:13283:36)
```

but only, when i want to load a navigation property from the junction table (ContactProfile) with includes like "Profiles.Contact" etc.

Everything on the serverside works very well, the database are also generated successfully.

Did i miss something?

**Edit:**

I've updated my data model. The exception only appears, when employer and the ContactProfile releationship are set:

```
var people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Jan Dae",
            LastName="Dae",
            Addresses = new List<Address>{addresses[0]},
            Employer = organizations[0] // Exception when both are set
        }
    };
people.ForEach(p => context.Contacts.Add(p));

var references = new List<ContactProfile>
    {
        new ContactProfile
            {
                Contact = people[0],
                Profile = organizations[0] //Exception when both are set
            }
    };
references.ForEach(r => context.ContactProfiles.Add(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your problem.

I can get results with or without '.Include("Profiles.Contact")'.

So you have an idea of how I tested it, I added your entities to the TODO sample, seeded the db, and queried.

Please provide a small solution (i.e. enable NuGet Package Restore and delete packages folder) showing the problem, so we can what could possibly be wrong. Send the solution to Breeze-Support@ideablade.com.

**Edit:**

I was able to reproduce the problem. I am checking with our senior engineer if this is indeed a bug.

By the way, while testing your solution I noticed that your Person-Organization association was not properly set. (even thought I still get the error after properly setting it up)

Note that Breeze associations requires foreign keys. Also, since it seems you are trying to set up a unidirectional association, you should use Fluent API:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Employer)
    .WithMany()     
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: I've updated my question and send a small sample @ breeze support mail.

Comment: Thanks. I got the sample and will take a look.

Comment: I'm looking at your sample, but it is not even seeding the DB as I'm getting a "Default values not supported" error on the context.SaveChanges() call. Since this is not the error you are reporting, so I'll leave up to you to handle this and send me a sample reproducing the original issue. The only change I made to your sample was to uncomment the connectionString entry in the web.config.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. SQL CE 4.0 doesn't support one field tables, so i have added the property 'Name' on my Contact model. I've resend my sample at breeze support mail.